# how to re-use kafka stream from not to open stream again and again

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Have created stream from topic and successfully retrieved my data based on the filter after stream.start(). but my problem is, when i try to filter again.. have to go through to create a builder and ksteram... these kStream will seek the data from topic starting offset 0 till end and produce the result .. however.. this browsing this topic from 0 all my request is not help to get appropriate SLA... is there a way we can achieve buy loading the stream one time and do the aggregation when ever i want?

I am always start and close my stream...

please help on how to achieve and any sample program would do

my sample program

```
  public class EventStream{
    public static void create stream(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "event_stream");
            props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
            props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
            props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());

            final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
            final KStream<String, Tracking> trackevent= build.stream("event",Consumed.with((serdes.String(),Serds.serderFrom(test.calss,test.class))));
            trackevent.filter((k,v) -> "test".equals(v.getStr())).foreach((k,v) -> System.Out.Println(V));
            trackevent.cleanUp();
            trackevent.start;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you `close()` the `KafkaStreams` instance? Did you try to set `auto.offset.reset` to `"latest"`?

Comment: tried both with close() and with out close() as well set auto.offset.reset=earliest.

Comment: when we do set auto.offset.reset=earliest and try to do the filter with my custom key .. it took me almost 24-30 hrs to get a desire response from 100 Million events from topic. one fact i noticed was, every time i run the filter  ... getting topic every time from the begining to collect the response. if you need a any detail log .. please let me know if you need any log to enable to check

Comment: just to added one more point ... keeping the kafkastream in a singleton class member variable.. stream is getting instantiated based on singleton object create and stream is getting closed at the time of context destroy

Comment: Could you describe in more detail, what would you like to achieve? Save some precalculate results and start later aggregation from that point? If you want to not filter several times just save the filtering results to topic and then work on that topic.

Comment: Why do you set "earliest" -- if you don't want to reprocess old data on startup, you should set "latest" as reset policy. Using a singleton for KafkaStreams does not sound correct. Try to change it. Also, you should always `close()` KafkaStreams client. One more question (just to make sure): you need to use the same `application.id` if you stop and restart.

Comment: That’s for the comments, what am trying to do is.. created a Joan records based on table records(almost 100 million) and open the same topic given to producer to send all real-time events.... so my topic is having old records as well as my new events from producer.. now, I created a stream on top of the topic .. stream contains..  all the data from topic along with new data(expected data from Producer) ... after all .. started the stream by calling Start() by passing he property... every time same property(same app if) with ‘ earliert\latest’ .... when start the filter ..

Comment: Every time .. to call filter .. have to start the stream correct, st this time .. am expecting all my latest and old records to be return based on the filter criteria... based on the filter response I would start my business processing..... not to the next topic to trap the filtered message..

Comment: Now the question is ... how to achieve this in stream .....